# Overpass turbo delivers no data and no errors

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-turbo

I am trying to use overpass-turbo.eu to get all relations for public transport in a set bounding box. I used to work with this query:

```
 <osm-script output="xml" timeout="25">
  <union>
    <query type="relation">
      <has-kv k="route" v="bus"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <recurse type="relation-way"/>
  </union>
  <print mode="meta"/>
  <print mode="meta" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

Trying to get data today the query suddenly appears to be not working anymore. I tried to narrow down my bbox (even making sure there will be just one bus line within my request) but the query just delivers no output. Exporting the geojson and importing it into GIS (QGIS 3.22 on Windows 10) I see all features and a fully filled in attribute table, but my relations just won't appear. Looking at the json, I can see that the coordinates are empty, see snippet below:

```
    "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "@id": "relation/10411607",
            "from": "Bochum Ruhr-Universität",
            "name": "Bus 339: Ruhr-Universität => Ruhr Park",
            "network": "VRR",
            "network:wikidata": "Q448199",
            "network:wikipedia": "de:Verkehrsverbund Rhein-Ruhr",
            "operator": "BOGESTRA",
            "operator:wikidata": "Q889060",
            "public_transport:version": "2",
            "ref": "339",
            "route": "bus",
            "to": "Bochum Ruhr Park",
            "type": "route",
            "@timestamp": "2022-01-14T23:49:10Z",
            "@version": "27",
            "@changeset": "116168007",
            "@user": "gmbo",
            "@uid": "577895",
            "@tainted": true
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiLineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [],
              [],
              [],
              [],
              [],
              [],
              [],
(...)
              [],
              [],
              [],
              []
            ]
          },
```

What am I doing wrong here? Did something change in overpass or OSM, so that my query doesn't work anymore?